# How to round float to bigger integer?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

In Google Sheet, we can use `ROUND()` to round float to the nearest.
like

```
5.2 = 5
5.5 = 6.
```

What if I want it:

```
5.2 = 6
5.5 = 6.
```

If the number exceeds by a decimal, then rounded off to +1.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ROUNDUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093443?hl=en)

> Rounds a number to a certain number of decimal places, always rounding up to the next valid increment.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ROUNDUP(A2; 0)
```




```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A); ROUNDUP(A1:A; 0); ))
```


[image: 1] [image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Round a floating number to upper integer, at first you have to import math

```
import math
```

then write

```
number =  math.ceil(3.2)


print(number)
```

`
output will be

```
4
```